# Grails: HIbernate-filter - Adding filter on mapped class column

Tags: grails, hibernate-filters, grails-filters

I want to use grails hibernate filter plugin to add a filter on of my domain class.

http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter

Domain classes:

```
class Movie {
    String name
    String genre
    String yearOfRelease
    boolean deleted
}

class EditRequest {
    String reason
    String requester
    Date   requestDate
    String status //can be 'PENDING', 'ONHOLD', OR 'COMPLETE'

    static belongsTo = [
            movie: Movie,
            requester: User
    ]
}
```

There could be multiple edit request for a movie.
I have an API where I need to display all edit requests for all non-deleted movies.
How do I add hibernateFilter for non-deleted movies in my EditRequest domain class

I tried below in my EditRequest class, but non of them works.

```
1. 
    static hibernateFilters = {
            deletedMovieFilter(condition:'deleted=false', default:true)
            deletedMovieFilter(collection:'movie', default: true)
      }


 2. 
  static hibernateFilters = {
         deletedMovieFilter(condition: 'deleted = false')
         deletedMovieFilter(collection: 'movie', joinTable: true)
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the "collection" attribute of hibernateFilters. If you don't get it to work, you can also use subselects in "condition", eg something like "movie_id in (select movie.id from movie where movie.deleted = false)". Also, remember that it doesn't work with .get().